# Accessing REST API with sessionId

Tags: rest, security, spring-mvc, session

I'm not understand how to get access to REST API if I already authorized.
I'm using Postman programm to send request and Spring MVC as backend

First I send request to get sessionId with header (basic authentication):
authorization Basic ODc3ODU1NTQyMDY6MTIzNA==

I recieved sessionId: 07C4E348CD645F6B73449D9916B13AE6
How I can send now sessionId to get access to other resources of REST API?

UPDATED:
   it's ok, if i want to get access from website. But what about mobile devices? it has no cookies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this to your header in the form of cookie :
 for example you have text/html with 49 length

```
  content type=text/html
  content length=49
  set cookie=sessionId: 07C4E348CD645F6B73449D9916B13AE6
```